# SAS: Find the seed used to generate random numbers

Tags: random, sas

Is it possible to find the seed SAS used to generate a set of random numbers?

For instance, if I run

```
data random;
  do i = 1 to 10;
    x = rand('uniform');
    output;
  end;
  drop i;
run;
```

and SAS produces a sequence of values which I like, can I find what seed generated that particular sequence of values?

Having the seed used for a particular run could be useful, for instance, in jittering data.  When I need to jitter data for a plot, I have to manually try different seeds to find one which doesn't have (too many) overlaps.  It would be simpler to let SAS pick the seed, run the jittering until the plot looks good, then set the seed to whatever value SAS happened to pick.

Comment: What information are you starting with?  Just the data? how much of it?  Is the number of bits available in the sample greater or smaller than the number of bits in the seed?  What if you just had partial recovery of the seed; would that suffice for your purposes? The system time is used by default; do you have knowledge of the approximate time that the seed was produced?

Comment: I am starting with the information given in the question: code used to generate some random numbers, the session executing the code, and the resulting random numbers.  Assuming you're correct about the system time, the question could be rephrased as, "How do I find the system time used to seed the random numbers generated on the last submit?"

Comment: Do you know how many bits of effective entropy are in the seed? If it is 32 or smaller then this problem is easy to solve. If it is big, say 64 bits or higher, then you have a significantly harder problem.

Comment: In short: let's suppose there are 32 bits of entropy in the seed. Write a program that generates all four billion seeds and gives you the first, say, thousand elements. Now make a map from the generated numbers back to the seeds that produced it. Put the whole thing in a database, and now you can easily solve your problem. Generating the four trillion numbers and putting them in a database shouldn't take more than a few hours, and you can parallelize it to multiple machines easily.

Comment: If you know the likely time that the seed was generated, then of course you don't have to try all four billion seeds. Just try all the ones that are within a few seconds of your target seed.

Comment: You might be amused by this article: https://ericlippert.com/2013/05/02/producing-permutations-part-six/

Comment: It sounds as though what you really need here is a way to automate the process of trying different seeds until you find one that has the properties you require - I suggest you close this question and post that as another one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the macro variable SYSRANDOM created by SAS when you use the RAND function.

```
28         data random;
29            *call streaminit(0);
30            do _n_ = 1 to 4;
31               x = rand('uniform');
32               output;
33               end;
34         
35            run;

NOTE: The data set WORK.RANDOM has 4 observations and 1 variables.

36         %put NOTE: &=sysrandom;
NOTE: SYSRANDOM=1065925276
```